# How to give permission storage.objects.list in google storage bucket?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to give permission storage.objects.list in google storage bucket?

I have already done with setting the service account and grant the roles of `storage. admin` and `storage. object.admin`

Comment: What are you trying to do? List the bucket content?

Answer (score 0):

Storage.objects.list permission comes under the following roles

1. Storage Object Viewer (roles/storage.objectViewer)
2. Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin)
3. Storage Admin (roles/storage.admin)
4. Storage Legacy Bucket Reader (roles/storage.legacyBucketReader)
5. Storage Legacy Bucket Writer (roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter)
6. Storage Legacy Bucket Owner (roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner)

So you have already given the storage.objects.list permission

You can also create custom roles that have the permissions that you require

You can refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) document for more information on IAM roles and permissions

Comment: Is there any command to set this permission? I have already done everything that had you mention.

Comment: Are you unable to list the objects? because the permission you are talking about is already included in that role which you have already provided. If you are not satisfied or having problem then you can go with custom roles. To create custom roles, go to the IAM and Admin-roles-create role-click on add permissions- select required roles and permissions and click add and then create. This will create a custom role for you.